# How to create a ttl index in mongodb atlas Using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm building a node app and using mongoose

This is my first time creating a TTL index on mongodb atlas, idk because for some reason it does not seem to work.

node version ***v14.16.0***

mongoose version ***5.12.5***

Comment: This might work: [Mongoose - SchemaDateOptions-expires](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schemadateoptions_SchemaDateOptions-expires). Also, check Atlas documentation if your _tier_ supports TTL indexes.

Comment: It works fine but showing, (node:7316) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.